# Scheduling tasks with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, background, scheduled-tasks

I have been going over rails scheduling tasks options and stumbled upon this piece of code from whenever.

```
case @environment
when 'production'
every 1.day, :at => "#{Time.parse('12:00 A').getlocal.strftime("%H:%M")}" do
   runner "Company.send_later(:create_daily_stories!)"
end 
when 'staging'
  every 15.minutes do
   command "thinking_sphinx_searchd  reindex"
  end
end
```

I am fairly new to ruby and I dont quite understand what "Company" here stands for. In other words say i want to send an email out to people and i have a controller class called email_controller in which I have a method called sendEmail and I want to send emails using this how would i do it? Should i say runner"email_controller.sendEmail" or something like that? I dont quite get it. Note - Do i use the model or controller in place of company?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, `Company` is an example model that has a class/singleton method called `create_daily_stories!`.  In theory, it would probably look like this:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Send out daily stories to all companies
  def self.create_daily_stories!
    # Do some stuff
  end
end
```

Ideally, generating emails resides in the business logic and should thusly be contained within a model (assuming you're using an MVC framework like rails).

Comment: Thank You. I will put that in a model! and call it from there. :D

Answer (score 1):

Resque is a great way to schedule tasks.
Take a look at [Resque Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque).

or possibly this [Rails: Cron Job Scheduling using Redis, Resque and Rufus](http://hemju.com/2011/03/04/rails-cron-job-scheduling-using-redis-resque-and-rufus/%22Rails%3a%20Cron%20Job%20Scheduling%20using%20Redis,%20Resque%20and%20Rufus%22).

Comment: Im not sure which one i should use though. The frequency of the task is maximum 1 per day. Is resque better?

Comment: @CodeGeek123 - We are doing all our scheduling in Resque, but we have many tasks that need running.  In the end, if it is working now, then go with that as less is more.

Comment: I tried your tutorial and I do not know how to test rufus-scheduler on the console. Also rake resque:scheduler in the resque scheduler gives a "rake aborted! Don't know how to build task 'resque:scheduler'" error.

Comment: @CodeGeek123 - I added a link to a RailsCast about Resque.